# How to save my data in external disk

Tags: ntfs

My hard drive is not mounting and I am not able to access any file.
It gives the following error message.

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to fragmentation problem of the NTFS partition. Since this is a forum for Ubuntu you can try to solve this from Ubuntu with the [`ntfsprogs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/quantal/ntfsprogs) programs (you might already have this installed otherwise: `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`). It includes a command to check NTFS.

```
ntfsck /dev/sdb1
```

Where I assume sdb1 is your disc (so you might need to change that).