# Mount error after power outage

Tags: mount

My Linux knowledge is rather limited, but I'll try to explain. Last night we had a power outage. When I restarted my server this morning I got an error message telling me that a disk failed to mount. Got the option to skip mounting and continue booting. Now when I try to mount the disk (media disk, not a system disk) I get this error:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda2: Command-line `mount "/mnt/sda2"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x04e2adc6  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 16595  usa_count: 25841: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x103f339f56a78da1) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x3).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
(udisks-error-quark)
```

Is there anyone that can give me some assistance. Would hate loosing 2 GB of my media files.

Comment: Please read the error message. The most logical solution is in the message: `run chkdsk /f on Windows`

Comment: Damn those people that maintain the `mount` software are so user friendly. Ever seen Microsoft tell you how to fix a problem with Ubuntu? :-P

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what to do: boot into windows, run `chkdsk /f` and reboot into windows twice more.

---

From Ubuntu (but only use this if you have not got a Windows system (better safe than sorry)):

```
ntfsck /dev/sda2
```

This is part of the ntfs-progs `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs` if not installed yet.

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254581/how-to-save-my-data-in-external-disk/254582#254582

Comment: Hmm, I'd be wary of using that actually. NTFS is a microsoft proprietary format, so I'd trust the MS tools more.

Comment: Oh that one works very reliably :) But OK only use it if all you have is Ubuntu

Comment: Just got this error when trying to use @Rinzwind suggestion: Error opening partition device: Permission denied. Think maybe easiest way will be to remove the disk and install it in my client computer which is running on windows7. ??